# Delphi / C++ Builder - Set active/selected row color in TDBGrid

Tags: c++, delphi, dbgrid, tdbgrid

I want to set the background color of the active/selected row in a TDBGrid control.

Using the OnDrawColumnCell event:

1) The following code will work if DBGrid has the option dgMultiSelect, if not, nothing happens:

```
if ( grid->SelectedRows->CurrentRowSelected ) {
    grid->Canvas->Brush->Color = clBlue;
}
```

2) The following code will work if DBGrid has the option dgRowSelect, if not, only the selected CELL, not the entire row, will be colored:

```
if ( State.Contains(gdSelected) ) {
    grid->Canvas->Brush->Color = clBlue;
}
```

How could I color the entire active/selected row without using dgRowSelect or dgMultiSelect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [OnDrawColumnCell](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.OnDrawColumnCell):

> An OnDrawColumnCell event handler can call the DefaultDrawColumnCell
>   method to instruct the data-aware grid to write the data value in the
>   cell.

Use [DefaultDrawColumnCell](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.DefaultDrawColumnCell) like this. This is Delphi code but you may convert it easy.

```
procedure TForm1.DBGridDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;const Rect: TRect; 
DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumnEh;State: TGridDrawState);
begin
.....    
  DBGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  DBGrid.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect,DataCol,Column,State);
....
```

**Update**

**How to paint the DBGrid active row, without setting dgRowSelect or dgMultiSelect.**

1. We need to get the top position of current row.

Define a class that inheritant of TDBGrid to make CellRect, Col and Row public:

```
type
  TMyDBGrid = class(TDBGrid)
  public
    function CellRect(ACol, ARow: Longint): TRect;
    property Col;
    property Row;
  end;

function TMyDBGrid.CellRect(ACol, ARow: Longint): TRect;
begin
  Result := inherited CellRect(ACol, ARow);
end;
```

Now we can check the top  of current cell in OnDrawColumnCell event :

```
procedure TMainForm.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);

var Col,Row : Integer;
begin
  col := TMyDbGrid(DBGrid1).Col;
  row := TMyDbGrid(DBGrid1).Row;
  if (Rect.Top = TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).CellRect(Col,Row).Top) and
                   (not (gdFocused in State) or not Focused) then
    DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;

  DBGrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect,DataCol,Column,State);
 end;
```

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for you answer. I'm already using this kind of code and already paint the rows. What I need to know is how to paint ONLY THE ACTIVE ROW, and without setting dgRowSelect or dgMultiSelect. In other words, how to determine the active row (note that State.Contains(gdSelected) and grid->SelectedRows->CurrentRowSelected not work in this case)

Comment: @sgm See uptate

Comment: There is no Focused var!

Comment: @sgm Really? [Focused](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TWinControl_Focused.html) is a method of TWinControl. Use the Focused method to see if the control is the active control. When Focused returns true, the control has the input focus. If Focused returns false, the user cannot interact with the control.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine with me

onDrawColumnCell Event

```
 var
  grid: TDBGrid;
  maskValue: String;
  aRect: TRect;
begin
  aRect := Rect;
  grid := Sender as TDBGrid;
  if (gdSelected in State) then
  begin
    maskValue := Column.Field.DisplayText;
    mydBGrid.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
    mydBGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
    grid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    DrawText(grid.Canvas.Handle, PChar(maskValue), length(maskValue), aRect,
      DT_SINGLELINE or DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER);
  end
  else
    grid.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```